# download picture from dropbox and watch it in one activity in android

Tags: android, dropbox

I have 3 activities in my Android app. The first one opens an ssh connection and on my raspberry pi it does different kind of things (running python scripts, uploading stuff to dropbox etc). This process generally takes 15-20 seconds and when it is ready, the second activity comes up where i click a button that downloads the files, and then, on the third activity i can see the files that my rpi made.

I want to make the the last two activity into one, so the user does not have to click anything to download his or her file. Which is the easiest way? Can I solve this with delays or threads or only the asynctask remains?

The file gets downloaded earlier in the same activity as this placePic function and then I call it:

**EDIT:**

```
public class dropboxDownloader extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

String apta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pic_show);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
        askPermissions();
    }

    AndroidAuthSession session = null;
    try {
        session = buildSession();
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dropboxAPI = new DropboxAPI<>(session);
    String[] fnames = null;
    DropboxAPI.Entry dirent = null;
    try {
        dirent = dropboxAPI.metadata("/", 1000, null, true, null);
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry> files = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
    ArrayList<String> dir = new ArrayList<String>();


    int i = 0;
    for (DropboxAPI.Entry ent : dirent.contents) {
        files.add(ent);// Add it to the list of thumbs we can choose from
        //dir = new ArrayList<String>();
        dir.add(files.get(i++).path);
    }

    apta = "something";

    Dir.mkdirs();

    final String DropboxDownloadPathTo = path + apta.substring(0, 30);
    final String DropboxDownloadPathFrom = apta;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    File file = new File(DropboxDownloadPathTo + DropboxDownloadPathFrom
            .substring(DropboxDownloadPathFrom.lastIndexOf('.')));
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        dropboxDownloader.dropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxDownloadPathFrom, null,
                outputStream, null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ez a hiba: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    placePic();
}


public void placePic() {

    backToMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    backToMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    goToMyPics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    goToMyPics.setOnClickListener(this);
    String this_pic = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/aha" + apta;
    Toast.makeText(this, "this_pic: " + this_pic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File f = new File(this_pic);
    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "delay begins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(dropboxDownloader.this, "delayed?", Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (apta.startsWith("/pi_pic_lc")) {
                    String dedo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                            "/aha/" +
                            apta;
                    Toast.makeText(dropboxDownloader.this, "open this: " + dedo, Toast
                            .LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        ali.setImageURI(Uri.parse(dedo));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(dropboxDownloader.this, "error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                } else {
                    String kutya = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                            "/aha/"
                            + apta;


                    Toast.makeText(dropboxDownloader.this, "open this: " + kutya, Toast
                            .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        ali.setImageURI(Uri.parse(kutya));
                        PhotoViewAttacher pv = new PhotoViewAttacher(ali);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(dropboxDownloader.this, "error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 5000);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "cant get you the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide code for both activities. it will make it much easier to help you

Comment: upload your code

Comment: I can't offer help with structuring your code, but please note that you're using the [Dropbox API v1 Android SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android). [Dropbox API v1 is deprecated and being retired soon](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should switch to the [Dropbox API v2 Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) instead.